# select uncommon records between two tables - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, table A and table B with the same column names. I want to fetch those records which are not present in table A but present in table B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join

```
Select * from tableb left join tablea on tableb.column = tablea.coulmn where tablea.column is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support `except` or `minus`.  But not MySQL.  I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1
                  from a
                  where a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and . . .
                 );
```

Note that this will not work if any columns have `NULL` values.

If you need to handle `NULL`s, you could use `(not a.col1 <=> b.col1) and (not a.col2 <=> b.col2) . . .`.  Or, you could use aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, . . .
from ((select a.*, 1 as is_a, 0 as is_b
       from a
      ) union all
      (select b.*, 0, 1
       from b
      ) 
     ) ab
group by col1, col2, . . .
having max(is_a) = 0 and max(is_b) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the rows are same if their primary keys are same (for example, id field). Than you can:

```
select id from b where id not in (select id from a)
```

If your tables has no primary keys or they do not match - you can alter the query to your tables structure.